# perl: show raw string, including special characters

Tags: string, perl

I want to print out the raw text of a string, without interpolating special characters.  So, for example, if my string is `"hello\nthere"`, I want to print that, rather than

```
hello
there
```

The string is stored in a variable, I'm not working with literals, so it's not just a matter of single-quote vs double-quote (I don't think). How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right incantation of `Data::Dumper` will do this.

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

$foo = "hello
there";
print Dumper $foo;         #  "hello\nthere"
```

Comment: btw, adding `$Data::Dumper::Ident=0;` will single-liine arrays and hashes.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print out the raw text of a string, without interpolating special characters.

That isn't really possible.

Escape sequences like `\n` are interpreted (not "interpolated") when the string is parsed. The source code ("raw text") that the string came from is not stored by the interpreter, so there isn't any way to retrieve it.

Tools like `Data::Dumper` can generate a string that's *probably* similar to the source code by automatically replacing control characters with their equivalent escape sequences, but this may not be identical to the original source representation. For instance, unnecessary backslashes (like `"this\ example"`) will not appear in the dumped representation, and nonstandard representations of escape characters (like `"\x0a"` for `\n`) will be replaced with standard ones.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$str="hello\nthere";

$str =~ s/\n/\\n/;

print "$str\n";
```

output:

`hello\nthere`

Comment: this would require running a search replace on every special character.